# Lookup from multiple reference

Tags: excel

I am looking a function that can enables me to lookup from multiple reference:
The case is like this :

I use a function to lookup data from another Excel file.

```
   |--ID Number----|---Name------|

   |--1234---------|-------------|
```

The value of name will be lookup from another excel file.
Then I create a macro, which can add one more row.

```
   |--ID Number----|---Name-----|

   |--1234---------|--Tony------|

   |--2345---------|------------|
```

The value for second row comes from different file from first row.
Function for that Macro listed like this:

```
Range("B4").Select     
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],[TEST.xlsx]Sheet1!R3C6:R1000C25,2,0)"
```

I want the source file, in this case *TEST.xlsx*, be different for each row. 
What function can I use to solve my problem?

Comment: You can use a helper column containing the filenames of the workbooks, then use `INDIRECT` function to pass it to `VLOOKUP`. But you need the workbooks source open when you evaluate the formula.

Comment: @L42 Thanks for your help. can you give me the source code to doing that?Because i have try to use INDIRECT function but it comes wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assuming you have Filenames on Column C (ID and Name - which contains the formula in A & B)

```
Dim myformula As String
Dim rngtofill As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> or whatever sheet
    Set rngtofill = .Range("B4", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cel In rngtofill
    myformula = "=VLOOKUP(" & cel.Offset(0, -1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
        ",[" & cel.Offset(0, 1).Value & "]Sheet1!R3C6:R1000C25,2,0)"
    cel.Formula = myformula
Next
```

Again, this is assuming you have *TEST.xlsx* in C4 and you have a fixed range to search to.
This is not using *INDIRECT* since you can apply VBA.

Comment: what is the meaning for function rngtofill?file TEST.xlsx is separated with the file i want to use the function.

Comment: @user3667535 That is the range you want to put your formula. I assumed that you adapted the use of a *Helper Column* which will contain the different filenames? And again the workbooks source should be open.

Comment: thanks for your response. I do not use Helper Column. I just use usual Vlookup that can refer to another file. can you give me explanation to use Helper column? Or can you put the function using excel spreadsheet here?

Comment: @user3667535 Oh. What I posted is a *SUB* which when run will put the required formula in Column B. You are referencing your *VLOOKUP* on different workbooks. Are these workbooks open or closed? Not clear yet.

Comment: I want to create macro that can function like a database. So I hope, when I fill ID Number, the result for name will be filled automatically based on other excel file. I use a macro that can enables me to add one more row, so that the database can be more flexible. In order to achieve that condition, I want to make the reference file can be change every time I add one more row. But the change of file's name will be sequence. For the example, TEST.xlsx for row 1 and when I add one more row, the reference file will be TEST2.xlsx. So the data will refer whether its workbooks open or closed